# How to disable Redis for Magento on Localhost?

Tags: magento-enterprise, redis, localhost, wamp

I can't turn off Redis within my Magento/Wampserver Installation. I have removed all lines referencing Redis in local.xml and it already shows as disabled in cm_redissessions.xml - But, when I visit the site via Wampserver I get a "There has been an error processing your request" page with the following associated error report. How do I disable Redis for a local installation of Magento?

```
a:4:{i:0;s:44:"Connection to Redis failed after 6 failures.";i:1;s:1809:"#0 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Credis\Client.php(362): Credis_Client->connect()
#1 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Credis\Client.php(362): Credis_Client->connect()
#2 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Credis\Client.php(362): Credis_Client->connect()
#3 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Credis\Client.php(362): Credis_Client->connect()
#4 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Credis\Client.php(362): Credis_Client->connect()
#5 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Credis\Client.php(447): Credis_Client->connect()
#6 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Credis\Client.php(440): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Cm\Cache\Backend\Redis.php(117): Credis_Client->select(0)
#8 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Zend\Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)
#9 C:\wamp\www\mysite\lib\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Mage_Cache_Back...', Array, true, true)
#10 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'Mage_Cache_Back...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#11 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#12 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#13 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
#14 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
#15 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#16 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 C:\wamp\www\mysite\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: you will have to stop redis from shell.

Comment: Yes, but how specifically do I do that when Magento is on localhost?

Comment: If you have commented out your REDIS Setup in your local.xml and you have restart apache then you should see your site.

Comment: It is commented out in local.xml and I have cleaned/flushed cache using n98-magerun and restarted wampserver and it is still running. I have checked every .xml file for any reference to redis. I can't stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally stopped Redis! Just commenting out and/or removing all references to Redis would not work. Not even restarting Wampserver would stop Redis. Not even flushing/clearing cache with n98-magerun would work. SO FINALLY I SIMPLY DELETED MY local.xml AND RECREATED IT WITHOUT ANY REFERENCES TO REDIS AND IT WORKED.

Answer (score 4):

In order to stop using REDIS, you simply need to remove the references from your `local.xml`. It's one thing to delete and start over but your must understand what you actually needed to do.

If you look you will see either one or both of the bellow sections, this is what you need to remove. Once it is removed clear your cache and you will be good to go.

```
<cache>
        <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket for better performance -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
            <persistent>1</persistent> <!-- persistence value, 0: not in use, > 0 used as persistence ID -->
        </backend_options>
    </cache>



<!-- example of redis full page cache -->
    <full_page_cache>
        <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket for better performance -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <database>1</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <!-- in FPC data is already gzipped, no need to do this twice -->
            <compress_data>0</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
            <lifetimelimit>43200</lifetimelimit> <!-- set lifetime for keys without TTL -->
            <persistent>2</persistent>
        </backend_options>
    </full_page_cache>
```